# Shape with an alternated bi-color border in android studio

Tags: android-studio, colors, border, shapes

I would like to create a shape to use as a background for an element, since the app has red and orange as main colors I would like to make a cool border, however I have only managed to find how to put a single color and don't really know how to do a sort of a design.
I would like to do something like this (I made this quickly in paint just a demonstration of my idea):

[Shape with cool alternated border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8sXH.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I worked on it a bit and came to a solution that isn't exactly what I was trying to do but it will be good enough I guess. This is the code to put in the xml file in the drawable  folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle"
            android:padding="10dp">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
                android:topRightRadius="20dp"/>

            <stroke
                android:width="10dp"
                android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle"
            android:padding="10dp">
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
                android:topRightRadius="20dp"/>

            <stroke
                android:width="8dp"
                android:color="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:dashGap="10dp"
                android:dashWidth="8dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

this code will produce this result:

[shape with bicolor border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4c3Aj.jpg)

Hope this helps anybody